# knockout data-bind to self-generated DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to apply a  data-bind to a self generated **DOM** Element after i initialized my **viewmodel**. But that doesn't seem to, work so i have the question: is it possible to get this data-bind work at all *(maybe with some kind of update function)* or not.

**for example:**

**html:**

```
<div id="content">
    <button onclick="create">create DOM ele</button>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable('TITLE');
    }

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());

function create() {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('data-bind', 'title()');

    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(div);
}
```

so the div will be created after pushing that button and the data-bind actually is an Attribute of the **DOMelement** if I look at the object with the Browser **Inspektor**, but the content of `viewmodel.title()` will never be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data-bind attributes are processed when applyBindings is run, which is finished long before  you trigger create(). You can run applyBindings during create() on the subtree of elements added to the page during create.

```
function create() {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('data-bind', 'title()');

  ko.applyBindings(
    new MyViewModel(),
    div;
  )
}
```

Comment: I agree with Tomalak.  Calling `ko.applyBindings` multiple times is very rarely a good idea in knockout.

Comment: There is a place where calling `ko.applyBindings()` is acceptable, and that place is not the view model, it is custom bindings that have `controlsDescendantBindings` enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong. You should not create DOM elements, that's what Knockout is for.

Your job is to manipulate the view model. Knockout's job is to manipulate the DOM.

```js
function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.title = ko.observable('TITLE');
  self.children = ko.observableArray();

  self.create = function () {
    self.children.push({
      name: "Child " + self.children().length
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
    <button data-bind="click: create">create item</button>
    <div data-bind="foreach: children">
      <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)" style="font-size: small;"></pre>
```

Comment: First of all thanks, you are fully right. The reason i did this was to create an overlay for webapplication which goes over the whole page with various inputs, divs... and is created and shown on a buttonhit. So i dont want to hardcode some html for this, cause content of this overlay varies. Do you have a idea to do this from a ko object?

Comment: I thought about to create a hidden container for the overlay with the ko visible binding instead of creating it when the application runs, im looking forward to hear your opinion.

Comment: @mushruptor Well, if the overlay is *fully* dynamic, i.e. it contains no bindings and its structure is unknown in advance, use a hidden container and the `html` binding. However, if the overlay is going to be the view for a viewmodel (inputs, buttons, bindings, etc), create an according sub-viewmodel, just like shown in my example above.

Comment: Yeah i totally forgot about the html binding.. its long time ago since i worked with knockout the last time and i try to get into it again. This overlay contains data-binds, in order to build up a JSON object. so will it work if i try to apply the data-binds to the sub-viewmodel in the html i get from the html-binding to my main-viewmodel?

Comment: I don't think the `html` binding should be used for that. I'd recommend creating [a template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).